# How do I get a character from a specific position in a 2D Array and store it in another variable?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, I have the array

```
OurTreats[][] BoxOfChocolates = new OurTreats[10][10];
```

(OurTreats is a class I created which contains an array with numbers from 0 to 7)

and I want the character stored in the position BoxOfChocolates[2][4] and store that character in a new variable int.

I've tried this

```
int character = BoxOfChocolates[2][4];
```

but that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Edit: The error that I get is "incompatible type, OurTreats cannot be converted to int"

OurTreats class code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class OurTreats {

    public void OurTreats() {
        OurTreats ot = new OurTreats();
        ot.treatNumbers();
    }

    public int treatNumbers() {
        int treat[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(treat.length);
        return (treat[num]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you can not assign the class you've made to an `int` variable, please provide the class code

Comment: @Mosius that was a mistake, in my code it's actually BoxOfChocolates. I'll provide the code

Answer (score 3):

`OurTreats` is a class that you have created and `BoxOfChocolates` is a 2-D array object of that class.
So basically what will be stored at `BoxOfChocolates[i][j]` is a single instance of `OurTreats` class.

So depending on your class definition I would suggest you try:

`int variable=BoxOfChocolates[2][4].DataMember`

*DataMember depends on your class definition so I have given it a generic name*
EDIT: 
On seeing your class definition. What you probably want to do is:

```
int character=BoxOfChocolates[2][4].treatNumbers();
```

Since you don't have an explicit data member, i think a call to the function will do what you need it to do, although i would suggest that you revamp your class definition.

Comment: @Bela I have made changes to the answer according to your class definition and I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

what about:

int character = BoxOfChocolates[2][4];

OurTreats is the class while BoxOfChocolates is the object or 1 instance of your class with data loaded in it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a mistake. My actual code had BoxOfChocolates[][] and not OurTreats, so it still doesn't work